# qt and ffmpeg - undefined reference

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg

I am building my first qt application and want to implement small operations with video BUT I am getting stupid error:

Here's my header file

```
#ifndef VIDEOPROCESSING_H
#define VIDEOPROCESSING_H

namespace ffmpeg {
    extern "C" {
        #include "libavformat/avformat.h"
    }
}
bool check_if_file_is_video(QString filePath);
#endif // VIDEOPROCESSING_H
```

Here's my cpp file

```
#include "video_processing.h"

bool check_if_file_is_video(QString filePath) {
    ffmpeg::AVFormatContext *s = NULL;
    ffmpeg::avformat_free_context(s);
}
```

I am getting such error:
**video_processing.cpp:6: error: undefined reference to `avformat_free_context'**

I tried with and out namespace, still doesn't work.

Am I missing anything obvious ?

Should I add to my .pro file anything to make it working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, thanks guys!
I needed to add to .pro file QMAKE_FLAGS directive with following value:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS = "-lavformat"
```